# Decorative functions for telethon?

Tags: python, telethon

I'm trying to make a custom decorator for telethon that will act kinda the same as the client.on(events.NewMessage()) but for some reason is not working at all.

This is my code:

```
def msg_out():
     def msg(func):
         def out(e, *args, **kwargs):
             if e.out:
                 return func(e, *args, **kwargs)
             else:
                 pass
         return out
     return msg
```

The function doesn't do nothing from what I've noticed so any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't do nothing"? It returns you another function object (`msg`). Please show how you intend to use this, and describe in more detail what happens, as well as what you would like to happen instead.

Comment: I want to make a shorter version of `@client.on(events.NewMessage(...)` that would also have custom arts like filters like how python telegram bot would do with the handlers. And for some reason it doesn't go to starting the function that has the decorator above it